# How to run SQL query repeatedly (in loop) with just two parameters changing for each run

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table "table_name" in SQL Server 2012 and I am using SQL Server Management Studio version 10.

Data in table looks like:

```
id          create_date     update_date     time_generated  kpname                      machine_name value_type     value
10706652    6/23/16 1:08 PM 6/23/16 1:08 PM 6/23/16 1:00 PM Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_Location BRAABBCCZ02 response_time   18.015
10707166    6/23/16 1:13 PM 6/23/16 1:13 PM 6/23/16 1:05 PM Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_Location BRAABBCCZ02 response_time   18.313
10707663    6/23/16 1:18 PM 6/23/16 1:18 PM 6/23/16 1:10 PM Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_Location BRAABBCCZ02 response_time   18
10708157    6/23/16 1:23 PM 6/23/16 1:23 PM 6/23/16 1:15 PM Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_Location BRAABBCCZ02 response_time   18.328
```

I have a dirty query that pulls data for past 6 weeks, for same day of the week and same time window of the day. The query is:

```
--wk1
select *
from table_name
where time_generated >= '2016-06-16 13:17:30'
  and time_generated <= '2016-06-16 13:22:29'
  and machine_name like 'BRAABBCCZ0%' 
  and kpname like '%Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_%'
  and value_type = 'response_time'

union

--wk2
select *
from table_name
where time_generated >= '2016-06-09 13:17:30'
  and time_generated <= '2016-06-09 13:22:29'
  and machine_name like 'BRAABBCCZ0%' 
  and kpname like '%Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_%'
  and value_type = 'response_time'

union

--wk3
select *
from table_name
where time_generated >= '2016-06-02 13:17:30'
  and time_generated <= '2016-06-02 13:22:29'
  and machine_name like 'BRAABBCCZ0%' 
  and kpname like '%Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_%'
  and value_type = 'response_time'

union

--wk4
select *
from table_name
where time_generated >= '2016-05-26 13:17:30'
  and time_generated <= '2016-05-26 13:22:29'
  and machine_name like 'BRAABBCCZ0%' 
  and kpname like '%Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_%'
  and value_type = 'response_time'

union

--wk5
select *
from table_name
where time_generated >= '2016-05-19 13:17:30'
  and time_generated <= '2016-05-19 13:22:29'
  and machine_name like 'BRAABBCCZ0%' 
  and kpname like '%Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_%'
  and value_type = 'response_time'

union

--wk6
select *
from table_name
where time_generated >= '2016-05-12 13:17:30'
  and time_generated <= '2016-05-12 13:22:29'
  and machine_name like 'BRAABBCCZ0%' 
  and kpname like '%Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_%'
  and value_type = 'response_time'
```

Is there any way I can run this same query (may be in loop or something) for different values of "time_generated"? For example I want to run this query 12 times to get data between 13:17:30 to 14:17:29 over five minute windows.

So I want to run above query 12 times for following values of time generated (date part will remain same, only time part will change)

```
13:17:30    13:22:29
13:22:30    13:27:29
13:27:30    13:32:29
13:32:30    13:37:29
13:37:30    13:42:29
13:42:30    13:47:29
13:47:30    13:52:29
13:52:30    13:57:29
13:57:30    14:02:29
14:02:30    14:07:29
14:07:30    14:12:29
14:12:30    14:17:29
```

Please suggest how I can do this and apologies for a lengthy (and probably confusing) question. I tried my best to describe it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to run in a loop or even multiple queries.

Just supply a few parameters

In this example, 1 query 72 subsets

```
Declare @DateStart Date = '2016-06-16'
Declare @WeeksBack Int  = 5
Declare @TimeStart Time = '13:17:30'
Declare @TimeCount Int = 12
Declare @TimeSpan  Int = 5

;With cteDate As (Select Wk=1,DateFrom = @DateStart Union All Select Wk=DF.Wk+1,DateFrom= DateAdd(DD, -7, df.dateFrom) From cteDate DF Where DF.DateFrom > DateAdd(WK,@WeeksBack*-1,@DateStart))
     ,cteTime as (Select RowNr=1,TimeFrom = @TimeStart Union All Select RowNr=Df.RowNr+1,TimeFrom= DateAdd(MINUTE, @TimeSpan, df.TimeFrom) From cteTime DF Where DF.RowNr < @TimeCount)
      Select B.*,A.*
       From  table_name A
       Join (Select WkName
                   ,DateR1=cast(KeyDate as datetime)+cast(TimeR1 as DateTime)
                   ,DateR2=cast(KeyDate as datetime)+cast(TimeR2 as DateTime)
             From (Select WkName=concat('Week ',Wk),KeyDate=DateFrom from cteDate) A
             Join (Select TimeR1=TimeFrom,TimeR2=DateAdd(SS,-1,DateAdd(MINUTE,@TimeSpan,TimeFrom)) from cteTime) B on 1=1
            ) B on time_generated Between DateR1 and DateR2
       Where machine_name like 'BRAABBCCZ0%' 
         and kpname like '%Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_%'
         and value_type = 'response_time'
```

The Subquery produces the following

```
WkName  DateR1                  DateR2
Week 1  2016-06-16 13:17:30.000 2016-06-16 13:22:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 13:17:30.000 2016-06-09 13:22:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 13:17:30.000 2016-06-02 13:22:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 13:17:30.000 2016-05-26 13:22:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 13:17:30.000 2016-05-19 13:22:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 13:17:30.000 2016-05-12 13:22:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 13:22:30.000 2016-06-16 13:27:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 13:22:30.000 2016-06-09 13:27:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 13:22:30.000 2016-06-02 13:27:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 13:22:30.000 2016-05-26 13:27:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 13:22:30.000 2016-05-19 13:27:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 13:22:30.000 2016-05-12 13:27:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 13:27:30.000 2016-06-16 13:32:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 13:27:30.000 2016-06-09 13:32:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 13:27:30.000 2016-06-02 13:32:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 13:27:30.000 2016-05-26 13:32:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 13:27:30.000 2016-05-19 13:32:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 13:27:30.000 2016-05-12 13:32:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 13:32:30.000 2016-06-16 13:37:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 13:32:30.000 2016-06-09 13:37:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 13:32:30.000 2016-06-02 13:37:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 13:32:30.000 2016-05-26 13:37:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 13:32:30.000 2016-05-19 13:37:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 13:32:30.000 2016-05-12 13:37:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 13:37:30.000 2016-06-16 13:42:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 13:37:30.000 2016-06-09 13:42:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 13:37:30.000 2016-06-02 13:42:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 13:37:30.000 2016-05-26 13:42:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 13:37:30.000 2016-05-19 13:42:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 13:37:30.000 2016-05-12 13:42:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 13:42:30.000 2016-06-16 13:47:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 13:42:30.000 2016-06-09 13:47:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 13:42:30.000 2016-06-02 13:47:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 13:42:30.000 2016-05-26 13:47:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 13:42:30.000 2016-05-19 13:47:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 13:42:30.000 2016-05-12 13:47:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 13:47:30.000 2016-06-16 13:52:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 13:47:30.000 2016-06-09 13:52:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 13:47:30.000 2016-06-02 13:52:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 13:47:30.000 2016-05-26 13:52:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 13:47:30.000 2016-05-19 13:52:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 13:47:30.000 2016-05-12 13:52:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 13:52:30.000 2016-06-16 13:57:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 13:52:30.000 2016-06-09 13:57:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 13:52:30.000 2016-06-02 13:57:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 13:52:30.000 2016-05-26 13:57:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 13:52:30.000 2016-05-19 13:57:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 13:52:30.000 2016-05-12 13:57:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 13:57:30.000 2016-06-16 14:02:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 13:57:30.000 2016-06-09 14:02:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 13:57:30.000 2016-06-02 14:02:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 13:57:30.000 2016-05-26 14:02:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 13:57:30.000 2016-05-19 14:02:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 13:57:30.000 2016-05-12 14:02:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 14:02:30.000 2016-06-16 14:07:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 14:02:30.000 2016-06-09 14:07:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 14:02:30.000 2016-06-02 14:07:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 14:02:30.000 2016-05-26 14:07:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 14:02:30.000 2016-05-19 14:07:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 14:02:30.000 2016-05-12 14:07:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 14:07:30.000 2016-06-16 14:12:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 14:07:30.000 2016-06-09 14:12:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 14:07:30.000 2016-06-02 14:12:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 14:07:30.000 2016-05-26 14:12:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 14:07:30.000 2016-05-19 14:12:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 14:07:30.000 2016-05-12 14:12:29.000
Week 1  2016-06-16 14:12:30.000 2016-06-16 14:17:29.000
Week 2  2016-06-09 14:12:30.000 2016-06-09 14:17:29.000
Week 3  2016-06-02 14:12:30.000 2016-06-02 14:17:29.000
Week 4  2016-05-26 14:12:30.000 2016-05-26 14:17:29.000
Week 5  2016-05-19 14:12:30.000 2016-05-19 14:17:29.000
Week 6  2016-05-12 14:12:30.000 2016-05-12 14:17:29.000
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using your solution as it gives me all the data in one single query. 12 data points for each week for past 6 weeks. Helped me a great deal and saved lot of manual effort.

Comment: Happy tp help.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

**Declare Variables**

```
Declare @Date  DATE = '2016-06-16';
Declare @Stime TIME = '13:17:30';
Declare @Etime TIME = '13:22:29';
```

**Query**

```
select *
from table_name
where machine_name like 'BRAABBCCZ0%' 
and kpname like '%Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_%'
and value_type = 'response_time'
and DATEPART(WEEKDAY,time_generated) =  5        -<-- WEEKDAY is Thursday   
AND time_generated >=  DATEADD(WEEK, -5,@Date)   -<-- Last 6 weeks 
and time_generated <= @Date
AND CAST(time_generated AS TIME ) >= @Stime      -<-- Time Window Open
AND CAST(time_generated AS TIME ) <= @Etime;     -<-- Time Window Close
```

Comment: Thank you M.Ali. Your answer is a neat and far better option for me to get same data as my dirty query above. I just had to modify it a little and change Declare Date  DATE = '2016-06-16'; to Declare Date  DATE = '2016-06-23'; else it was skipping June/16 date. Also Changed DATEADD(WEEK, -5,Date) to DATEADD(WEEK, -6,Date) to go back 6 weeks.

Comment: Note: I was unable to use code tag and so was getting error for using @, so I had to remove those from code lines.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try to make this work using Dynamic SQL.

```
`SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE
@x as varchar(2) = 0,
@sql as VARCHAR(8000), 
@date1 as datetime =  '2016-05-12 13:17:30',
@date2 as datetime =  '2016-05-12 13:22:30'  
WHILE @x < 60
BEGIN
SET @sql = 'SELECT * 
  FROM table_name 
  WHERE time_generated >= '''+CONVERT(varchar, @date1)+''' 
    AND time_generated <= ''' + CONVERT(varchar, @date2)+ '''
    AND machine_name like ''BRAABBCCZ0%''
    AND kpname like ''%Win-RT7_Abc Onetwo_%''
    AND value_type = ''response_time'''                        
Execute(@sql)  
SET @date1 = DATEADD(minute,5,@date1)
SET @date2 = DATEADD(minute,5,@date2)
SET @x = @x + 5  
END
END`
```

This should hopefully give you your desired output. You can modify it to increase the Datepart as well if you wanted to run all 6 weeks at the same time.

Every time this query loops the time in incremented by +5 minutes and then the query is executed. You can play with the @x variable to adjust how many times you would like to loop. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you. With your suggestion I could get all the data with least manual changes.